# spring-integration-aws vs aws-java-sdk for simple read and write operations to S3

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, spring-integration-aws

I need to access AWS S3 to read and upload some json files. The use cases i have are:

1. Retrieve a json file based on the ObjectId from S3 and extract certain fields out of the json.
2. Write a json file to S3, and sometimes re-write/update the same file based on ObjectId.

The application i need to implement the above use cases is an existing Spring Boot Application.

I am debating whether to use the "aws-java-sdk-s3", or "spring-integration-aws" to perform this task. I feel the aws-java-sdk-s3 API is nice and simple, and  AmazonS3, S3Object, GetObjectRequest, PutObjectRequest seems to do the job for me.

But, i was wondering if i need to consider using spring-integration-aws instead. There are inbound and outbound adapters for S3, but i don't have a need for service orchestration or routing. So, spring-integration-aws seems overkill.

Can i get some feedback and suggestions based on your experiences and the information i have provided? Appreciate the suggestions